# Get router mac (without system call for ARP) in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, bash, macos

Ok - I am writing a daemon in Objective C that checks the connected router mac address every 5 seconds.

I am completely new to objective C, and I am looking for a better way to do what I'm already doing.

I'm currently calling "arp -a" and parsing the results via "Task":

```
NSTask *task;
task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[task setLaunchPath: @"/usr/sbin/arp"];

NSArray *arguments;
arguments = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"-a", nil];
[task setArguments: arguments]; 

NSPipe *pipe;
pipe = [NSPipe pipe];
[task setStandardOutput: pipe];

NSFileHandle *file;
file = [pipe fileHandleForReading];

[task launch];

NSData *data;
data = [file readDataToEndOfFile];
```

I'm afraid that this isn't very efficient.

Any suggestions? I am running this codeblock once every 5 seconds.

Comment: First, I just want to clear up that "arp -a" is not a system call. A system call is a special function that is really a hook into the Operating System. It seems like you just don't want to use an external program, not system call. Examples of system calls are like read(), write(), socket(), etc.

Comment: sorry about that. I'm new to the language, especially the terminology.  Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Can you say why you are trying to do this?  OS X already provides various network monitoring and configuration services that might be more useful than rolling your own.

Comment: is there a utility that can monitor the router that the Airport is connected to? If there is, I haven't been able to find it. I need to run specified configuration scripts based on changes in access point connection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apple's implementation of `arp` is open source.  Take a look at [the file](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/bootp/bootp-133.8/bootplib/arp.c) for an idea of its implementation... it's not terribly convoluted.  It is pure ANSI C, though.

You should be able to simply copy-paste the majority of the functionality... and instead of printing the results, just store the raw address.

**Edit:** Here's a stripped down version of the source that just runs the equivalent of `arp -a`.  This should compile without any special directives.

```
/*
 * Copyright (c) 1999 Apple Computer, Inc. All rights reserved.
 *
 * @APPLE_LICENSE_HEADER_START@
 * 
 * This file contains Original Code and/or Modifications of Original Code
 * as defined in and that are subject to the Apple Public Source License
 * Version 2.0 (the 'License'). You may not use this file except in
 * compliance with the License. Please obtain a copy of the License at
 * http://www.opensource.apple.com/apsl/ and read it before using this
 * file.
 * 
 * The Original Code and all software distributed under the License are
 * distributed on an 'AS IS' basis, WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EITHER
 * EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, AND APPLE HEREBY DISCLAIMS ALL SUCH WARRANTIES,
 * INCLUDING WITHOUT LIMITATION, ANY WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
 * FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE, QUIET ENJOYMENT OR NON-INFRINGEMENT.
 * Please see the License for the specific language governing rights and
 * limitations under the License.
 * 
 * @APPLE_LICENSE_HEADER_END@
 */


#include <sys/param.h>
#include <sys/file.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/sysctl.h>

#include <net/if.h>
#include <net/if_dl.h>
#include <net/if_types.h>
#include <net/route.h>

#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netinet/if_ether.h>

#include <arpa/inet.h>

#include <err.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <nlist.h>
#include <paths.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static int nflag;

void
ether_print(cp)
    u_char *cp;
{
    printf("%x:%x:%x:%x:%x:%x", cp[0], cp[1], cp[2], cp[3], cp[4], cp[5]);
}


/*
 * Dump the entire arp table
 */
int
dump(addr)
    u_long addr;
{
    int mib[6];
    size_t needed;
    char *host, *lim, *buf, *next;
    struct rt_msghdr *rtm;
    struct sockaddr_inarp *sin;
    struct sockaddr_dl *sdl;
    extern int h_errno;
    struct hostent *hp;
    int found_entry = 0;

    mib[0] = CTL_NET;
    mib[1] = PF_ROUTE;
    mib[2] = 0;
    mib[3] = AF_INET;
    mib[4] = NET_RT_FLAGS;
    mib[5] = RTF_LLINFO;
    if (sysctl(mib, 6, NULL, &needed, NULL, 0) < 0)
        err(1, "route-sysctl-estimate");
    if ((buf = malloc(needed)) == NULL)
        err(1, "malloc");
    if (sysctl(mib, 6, buf, &needed, NULL, 0) < 0)
        err(1, "actual retrieval of routing table");
    lim = buf + needed;
    for (next = buf; next < lim; next += rtm->rtm_msglen) {
        rtm = (struct rt_msghdr *)next;
        sin = (struct sockaddr_inarp *)(rtm + 1);
        sdl = (struct sockaddr_dl *)(sin + 1);
        if (addr) {
            if (addr != sin->sin_addr.s_addr)
                continue;
            found_entry = 1;
        }
        if (nflag == 0)
            hp = gethostbyaddr((caddr_t)&(sin->sin_addr),
                sizeof sin->sin_addr, AF_INET);
        else
            hp = 0;
        if (hp)
            host = hp->h_name;
        else {
            host = "?";
            if (h_errno == TRY_AGAIN)
                nflag = 1;
        }
        printf("%s (%s) at ", host, inet_ntoa(sin->sin_addr));
        if (sdl->sdl_alen)
            ether_print((u_char *)LLADDR(sdl));
        else
            printf("(incomplete)");
        if (rtm->rtm_rmx.rmx_expire == 0)
            printf(" permanent");
        if (sin->sin_other & SIN_PROXY)
            printf(" published (proxy only)");
        if (rtm->rtm_addrs & RTA_NETMASK) {
            sin = (struct sockaddr_inarp *)
                (sdl->sdl_len + (char *)sdl);
            if (sin->sin_addr.s_addr == 0xffffffff)
                printf(" published");
            if (sin->sin_len != 8)
                printf("(weird)");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return (found_entry);
}

int main (int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    dump(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For some reason, after downloading both arp.c and arp.h, I can't compile this...

Thoughts?

Comment: Yeah, they do some funny stuff with `#define`.  I've added a workable, completely standalone implementation of just `arp -a` to my answer.

Comment: this is quite excellent - very good learnin' moment for me here. Thank you very much.

Comment: First, thank you very much for this eleborate answer. I am trying to get this code running on an IOS device. 
It works nicely on the simulator (xcode 4.0.1). However, when compiling for a device I get No such file on: net/if_types.h, net/route.h, netinet/if_ether.h and nlist.h

Thank you in advance

Comment: @Lior: You should submit that as a new and independent question.  I am not very familiar with iOS, but someone else may be able to help you.  Note that for my stripped-down code sample above, not all of those header files are necessary; `<sys/param.h>`, `<sys/file.h>`, `<sys/socket.h>`, `<net/if.h>`, `<net/if_types.h>`, `<netinet/in.h>`, `<nlist.h>`, and `<paths.h>` may all be omitted.

Comment: Excuse me , what the value of addr should I input for get the entire arp table when you call `dump(addr)` ?

Comment: @MattB. : I have add the `ARP.c` and `ARP.h` into my `X-code project`. But it doesn't has `dump` define in `ARP.h`. How to use this source code to get the ARP table ? I am new for IOS , Can you give me some help for using ARP ? I have ask the independent question in [How to use ARP.c to get the ip address in the ARP table in Objective-C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22930477/how-to-use-arp-c-to-get-the-ip-address-in-the-arp-table-in-objective-c).

Comment: where i can find ARP.c and ARP.h files......i googled but didm.t find...please help