# What is POCO_NO_NET_IFTYPES used for?

Tags: poco-libraries

I'm trying to understand what this variable is for.  It would appear it needs to be used for iOS builds because you can't access the MAC address on iOS devices?

If it's not defined, line #1349 in NetworkInterface.cpp fails with "file not found" at compile time:
    #include

Is my assessment correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your assessment is correct. If there is no net/if_types.h header on a platform, some types are not defined. The consequence is that those types will [not be detected](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/2bbff0ca8f9483e8cdab323d8603413a8bc09395/Net/src/NetworkInterface.cpp#L1365-L1375) during the discovery of the interface type and interface will be reported to be of [NI_TYPE_OTHER](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/2bbff0ca8f9483e8cdab323d8603413a8bc09395/Net/src/NetworkInterface.cpp#L1376) type.

For some reason, although Apple [provides the header](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-2782.1.97/bsd/net/if_types.h), it is [not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024266/why-does-this-code-works-on-xcode-simulator-but-does-not-work-on-device) on iPhone devices.

This shortcoming will affect you if you need to know exactly what is the type of the interface; you should be able to [discover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14334076/what-exactly-means-ios-networking-interface-name-whats-pdp-ip-whats-ap) that from the interface name.

Comment: Thanks!  We do need to know if we're on a wi-fi or cellular connection, but I'm pretty sure that info. is available in other ways if not via Poco.  We also need to know the IP address for Geofencing purposes, but Poco probably still provides that.