# Implicit declaration of function 'ether_ntoa' is invalid in C99

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

It's part of a series of functions that retrieve IP & Mac addresses from the phone.

```
strcpy(temp, (char *)ether_ntoa((const struct ether_addr *)LLADDR(sdl)));
```

EDIT: No equivalent function needed, there were just a few missing headers.

EDIT: Added cast to LLADDR(sdl)

Comment: It appears to be, despite saying it's a Mac OS X manpage, it is included in the iOS Development Library. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/ether_ntoa.3.html

Comment: Take a look at the Objective C code at this link which might help you from "amcgregor". https://gist.github.com/1265265

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As I read it, the error message isn't claiming that the function is missing, only that you don't include its declaration.  (I don't **know** that it exists, only that the message has a different complaint.)

In case it helps, `man ether_ntoa` tells me:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <net/ethernet.h>
```

Comment: Looks like I was missing #include <net/ethernet.h>. However now I get the new error: `"Incompatible pointer types passing 'caddr_t' (aka 'char *') to parameter of type 'const struct ether_addr *'"`. I guess this is a casting-related error?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `LLADDR` but, since the `ether_ntoa` parameter is said to be `const struct ether_addr *`, I'd guess that you're right about the cause of the problem.

Comment: Ok, the error in the comment above was a type error with the parameter passed to `ether_ntoa()`, because `LLADDR(sdl))` returns a `char *` but `ether_ntoa()` takes something else. Fixed with the cast: `ether_ntoa((const struct ether_addr *)LLADDR(sdl)))` and all appears to still be working.

Answer (score 0):

I included following header file and source code compiled successfully:

```
#import <arpa/inet.h>
```