# How to get Wi-Fi router IP address on iOS?

Tags: ios, wifi, ip-address, router

Is there any way to get Wi-Fi router IP address on iOS from my application?
[image]

With help of getifaddrs(struct ifaddrs **) method I can get interface address, subnet mask, broadcast address, but cannot get router address.
I have found a lot of solutions for Mac OS, but not for iOS.

Any solutions for iOS?

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113580/objective-c-how-to-fetch-the-router-address

Comment: Give this a try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16470615/is-it-possible-to-get-the-ssid-mac-address-of-currently-connected-wifi-network

Comment: No one of the comments above is applicable for getting wi-fi router ip-address on iOS device.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution @Alena ?

Comment: For 7 iOS it is not resolvable, but I didn't try with 8 iOS.