# How to get the wifi mac address on iPhone in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, mac-address

Is there a way to get the real Wi-Fi MAC address of the IOS device using Swift language?
Code snippet much appreciated!
Thanks.

Comment: [Relevant Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16470615/is-it-possible-to-get-the-ssid-mac-address-of-currently-connected-wifi-network)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

When you request the Device MAC address in iOS 7 and above you will always get the same response: **02:00:00:00:00:00**, this has been made by [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS7.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013162-SW1) for privacy concerns.

> In iOS 7 and later, if you ask for the MAC address of an iOS device, the system returns the value 02:00:00:00:00:00. If you need to identify the device, use the identifierForVendor property of UIDevice instead. (Apps that need an identifier for their own advertising purposes should consider using the advertisingIdentifier property of ASIdentifierManager instead.)

Apple recommends to switch to `UDID` instead if you need to uniquely identify an iOS device. In `Swift` you can use this:

```
UIDevice.currentDevice().identifierForVendor
```

if you want a string instead use:

```
UIDevice.currentDevice().identifierForVendor.UUIDString
```

[Here](http://nshipster.com/uuid-udid-unique-identifier/)'s a nice reading about UDID

Comment: Swift 3.1: `UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor.uuidString`

Comment: Keeping in mind that identifierForVendor.UUIDString changes every time you delete and reinstall your application.

Answer (score 6):

You can not get mac address because of some security concerns. you may use UUID instead to identify device uniquely.

for swift 4.2

```
UIDevice().identifierForVendor?.uuidString ?? ""
```

for objective c

```
[[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString]
```

Answer (score 5):

This is no longer possible since iOS 7, due to privacy risks Apple does not allow developers to access any device specific identifiers.

Answer (score 0):

For iOS 15 do this:

```swift
UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor?.uuidString
```