# Can I programmatically get the MAC address of wifi which is connected to my phone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

My phone is connected to wifi.I want to get mac address of my wifi.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29164734/6469239

Comment: yes it is duplicate but is it possible or not?

Comment: @AnisMansuri It's not possible after iOS 7.0. If you request the mac ID, you'll always get `02:00:00:00:00:00`. Check the answer in the link above.

Comment: @ebby94 that sentence is for device mac address. I'm talking about wifi mac address. Both are different. Check last paragraph of this document. (https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS7.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013162-SW1)

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/16474591/3066450

Comment: MAC of Wifi xD nice one. Do you mean IP address?
if soo look at 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6807788/how-to-get-ip-address-of-iphone-programatically

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to get the SSID & MAC Address of Currently connected WiFi Network in an App](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16470615/is-it-possible-to-get-the-ssid-mac-address-of-currently-connected-wifi-network)

Answer (score 6):

BSSID and mac address is same thing.
You can get mac address from this function.
just import SystemConfiguration.CaptiveNetwork

```
func getWIFIInformation() -> [String:String]{
    var informationDictionary = [String:String]()
    let informationArray:NSArray? = CNCopySupportedInterfaces()
    if let information = informationArray {
        let dict:NSDictionary? = CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo(information[0] as! CFStringRef)
        if let temp = dict {
            informationDictionary["SSID"] = String(temp["SSID"]!)
            informationDictionary["BSSID"] = String(temp["BSSID"]!)
            return informationDictionary
        }
    }

    return informationDictionary
}
```

Comment: Works well on real device. On simulator it returns empty data. Thanks for help! :)

Comment: In order to use this you need to add `import SystemConfiguration.CaptiveNetwork`

Comment: BSSID is not the same thing with mac address.