# How does fing app still getting mac address although it is not allowed in iOS 11

Tags: swift, ios11, ios12

I need to get mac address of device.I know it is not possible after iOS 11 but somehow [Fing app](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=2ahUKEwiOxrDdsc7eAhUozYUKHbzvDukQFjAAegQICRAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fitunes.apple.com%2Fpk%2Fapp%2Ffing-network-scanner%2Fid430921107%3Fmt%3D8&usg=AOvVaw2nTKekkPaanOUAGhT1R8_4) still getting mac address for some devices.How it possible .I need to achieve exactly same things which described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27099108/how-does-ios-app-fing-get-mac-address) but this answer was for iOS7 but now current version is iOS 12.for help i uploaded Fing app Screen shoot from my Iphone

Comment: Which “iOS 7-specific” answer are you referring to?

Comment: thanks @MartinR for your reply. I was refring this one (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27099108/how-does-ios-app-fing-get-mac-address)

Comment: You can try private API, but apple will not allow you to submit app in appstore

Comment: @canister_exister then how Fing app getting mac address even though it is downloadable from app store

Comment: if you want your device mac you need private api, for wifi routers mac you don't need.  There is a lot information about it, just search better. https://stackoverflow.com/a/41542212/4311935