# Find IBeacon mac address programmatically Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3

I have developed Android application where I am catching beacon signal on the bases of MAC Address...
      Currently I have to develop same in IOS using Swift, In Swift I am not able to get MAC Address but if I start doing by UUID my server side whole logic get changed because in server I am using same Database and same  program to parse t . Is there any way to get MAC address in ibeacon.

Comment: May be this will help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29163110/how-to-get-the-wifi-mac-address-on-iphone-in-swift

Comment: Would you mind sharing the solution if you happened to find it?

Comment: @inigo333 I just tried to find out solution and got some information that even if i manage to get mac address using some third party api then actually i am violating the rule and app store will not accept my app. so now i am trying to do using major and minor value . If you find some solution please share..