# Mac Address / Device name detection using ip address in iOS

Tags: ios

I am creating an app in which I have to show all the devices which are connected on a particular wi-fi network. I have all the IP addresses which are connected to  wi-fi. Can anyone please help me out in how to find out the mac address/ device name from an ip  address of all the connected devices ...

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is not working? Have you checked if there is any Apple example code?

Comment: For the MAC address you can examine the ARP table - this question may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10395041/getting-arp-table-on-iphone-ipad. For device name, it is harder - you can try DNS but on a typical home wifi it probably won't help

Comment: @Paulw11, I already tried this link, but not working. getting error at same place i.e  sdl = (struct sockaddr_dl *)(sin + 1);