# How to get client list of Hotspot in IOS in objective-C?

Tags: ios

I am developing an application where I have to turn on the **`Hotspot`** and get the information of client which connected to this **`Hotspot`**.

It seems can not turn on the **`Hotspot`** via **`objective-C`**.

If I turn on the **`Hotspot`** on My iPhone settings. 
Is it possible to get the information of client , like **`IP address`** , **`MAC address`** ??

like the following:

**Client List**

IP  :192.168.XX.XX

MAC :XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX

**`The question:1`**

Can I turn on the hotspot via objective-c in iOS 7?

**`The question:2`**

Is it possible to get the information of client(like **`IP address`** , **`MAC address`**) which connected to this hotspot ??

Comment: about Q2 I sure you can do this, when I searched way to get local MAC I found the way how to get all ip and macs in local network

Comment: How to do ? do you have some sample or information for it ?

Comment: I hope my answer help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question #2 requirements meets structure names  [**ARP table**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Resolution_Protocol)

so all you need is play with code provided in those answers and make it work on interface that linked to Hotspot:

[Getting ARP table on iPhone/iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10395041/1403732)

[How do I query the ARP table on iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2258172/1403732)

Comment: So...Does the `hotspot server` must be use the `ARP table` to get the client ? Is it for Apple API ?

Comment: ARP table is system wide structure, to create any network connection operation system first resolve hardware address and store it in ARP table. This true for any OS, and not related to API. In other words hotspot just won't work without ARP.

Comment: @sager444 Excuse me , I am new for this. **It seems the `ARP` can get the `MAC address` from the known IP address , wright ?** But How do I know the `IP address` of client which connected to the `Hotspot` server ?

Comment: or **Can I get the both of IP address and MAC address from the ARP table ?**

Comment: ok. Let me explain. Hotspot software assign ip address to each client that connected and write row with `ip` and `mac` (and some other data like ttl, but this not related to our problem) to system ARP table (for caching), as you already know ARP is protocol that resolve `mac` to `ip` and ARP table is cache of currently known network clients. @Martin if this is still not clean for you, feel free to ask.

Comment: I have saw the link , but I don't understand how the code work...I am new in objective-c. Should I call `-(NSString*) ip2mac: (char*) ip` for get the `IP address` in `ARP table` ?

Comment: or How to use it ? only cop and past the code and call the function in first link [Getting ARP table on iPhone/iPad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10395041/getting-arp-table-on-iphone-ipad)?

Comment: This code looks for only one mac/ip, you need a bit rewrite it to get entire table. Yes for first look this samples too hard, but if you play with debugger and read manual about functions and structures you will can use it. I think there is no another way to get info you want so adopt those examples or don't do this at all. Oh yes, you can ask another question maybe someone do it for you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have search for this link [Get router mac (without system call for ARP) in Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189200/get-router-mac-without-system-call-for-arp-in-objective-c). I am not sure , but it seem can dump the entire arp table. I will try it.

Comment: Excuse me , I have add the code in [How do I query the ARP table on iPhone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2258172/how-do-i-query-the-arp-table-on-iphone). But I am not familiar with Objective-C. How to call the function `-(NSString*) ip2mac: (char*) ip` ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no API for that. the hotspot isnt part of your app.

Comment: Do you have any idea for getting `IP address` of client which connected to `hotspot` ?