# how can i get hotspot connected devices ip address and MAC address in ios iphone swift?

Tags: ios, mac-address

My requirement is like, I want IP and MAC address of devices which are connected to my iOS device's hotspot.
How can I get a list of IP address of those devices?
Does Apple allow to get hotspot related information through code.?

Comment: @DixitAkabari thanks for your comment but it's not giving the list of IP addresses which are connected to personal hotspot,  it is working fine when using wifi network.

Comment: @gaurgtm did you ever resolve this?

Comment: Is there any open source or Swift API to achieve this?

Comment: Adding a bounty to this as I really need this feature in one of my apps, I've downloaded apps which have this capability so I know that this is possible. Hoping that someone can provide a solution to this. Cheers

Comment: Hey, check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22807795/how-to-get-client-list-of-hotspot-in-ios-in-objective-c 
it may be the thing u are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't know a way to get the actual client list (or ARP table for that matter).

But you could implement a scanner. Have you thought of that? Isn't the beautiful solution you're most probably looking for, but might be something?

Here would be a scanner library as reference: https://github.com/mavris/MMLanScan

You could also get your devices IP address and network mask, calculate the possible IP range yourself and implement an ARP query per candidate device using `sysctl` and `gethostbyaddr` as described in this post

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2269903/1041122

EDIT sidenote:
Did you have a really deep read of the [NetworkExtension](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension) API from Apple? I don't know it well but since it allows numerous configurations that *might* be possible as well.