# Get connected wifi Router's manufacturer name

Tags: ios, swift, wifi, mac-address

I am working on application where i need to get mobiles wifi Router's manufacturer name(EX:: Kasda Network Inc or Huawei technologies co. ltd ).Here an [app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/network-analyzer-pro/id557405467?mt=8) which shows Vendor name like Below.
How can i get exact information about vendor like below
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a unique device ID in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25925481/how-to-get-a-unique-device-id-in-swift)

Comment: @ElTomato thanks .actually i am searching for [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189200/get-router-mac-without-system-call-for-arp-in-objective-c]  but i think this is for mac os butt i needed for iOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question contains two parts.

1:How to get Mac Address of connected wifi

2:On base of that Mac address get manufacturer name

1:getting Mac address

```
func getConnectedWifiMacAdrees()-> [String:String]{
        var informationDictionary = [String:String]()
        let informationArray:NSArray? = CNCopySupportedInterfaces()
        if let information = informationArray {
            let dict:NSDictionary? = CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo(information[0] as! CFString)
            if let temp = dict {
                informationDictionary["BSSID"] = String(temp["BSSID"]as!String)
                return informationDictionary
            }
        }

        return informationDictionary
    }
```

NOTE::import SystemConfiguration.CaptiveNetwork

2:get to know about which mac address belongs from which manufacturer .Download latest manufacturer data from IEEE portal [here](http://standards-oui.ieee.org/oui/oui.txt) or [here](https://regauth.standards.ieee.org/standards-ra-web/pub/view.html#registries)

Answer (score 0):

try with this

```
import SystemConfiguration.CaptiveNetwork
func getSSID() -> String? {

        let interfaces = CNCopySupportedInterfaces()
        if interfaces == nil {
            return nil
        }

        let interfacesArray = interfaces as! [String]
        if interfacesArray.count <= 0 {
            return nil
        }

        let interfaceName = interfacesArray[0] as String
        let unsafeInterfaceData =     CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo(interfaceName as CFString)
        if unsafeInterfaceData == nil {
            return nil
        }

        let interfaceData = unsafeInterfaceData as! Dictionary <String,AnyObject>

        return interfaceData["SSID"] as? String
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Pushp for your reply you are giving me SSID but I need to get Vendor name .I have update screen shoot please review it for selected area.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidevice/1620059-identifierforvendor

Comment: @AyazAkbar thanks .actually i am searching for [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189200/get-router-mac-without-system-call-for-arp-in-objective-c]  but i think this is for mac os butt i needed for iOS

Comment: I did not get vendor name Please help me for finding the vendor name.

Comment: How to get Vendor name?