How can I get the destination MAC address of the node my macOS device is connected to in C?
So I'm implementing TCP sockets in C with raw sockets in order to further understand computer networking. I'm working on writing the ethernet header code, and I can get the source MAC address that's burned onto my NIC with the getifaddrs, but I'm not sure how to get the destination MAC address. In FreeBSD which MacOS is based off of, it looks like you can use the ioctl syscall, but it seems MacOS removed the feature of getting the MAC address through that syscall. Is there some way of making an ARP request that's common knowledge on MacOS that I don't seem to be able to find any information about? The next best solution I've found is parsing the arp command, but that seems horribly inefficient to me and like there should be an easier way of doing this.
Any help would be much appreciated, I've spent a bit too much time scanning through ifconfig.c and random header files!

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189200/get-router-mac-without-system-call-for-arp-in-objective-c

To get the destination MAC address (the one your macOS device is connected to) you’re on the right track by thinking about ARP (Address Resolution Protocol) On macOS you won’t be able to use the ioctl syscall for this like in FreeBSD but there’s still a way you can handle it One option is to send an ARP request manually to the destination IP to ask for its MAC address. ARP works by mapping IP addresses to MAC addresses in a local network you can approach it doing teh below steps :

You create and send an ARP packet to ask the destination node What's your MAC address?


The device on the other end responds with its MAC address which you can then use

However writing raw ARP packets in C might be more complex than you'd like A simpler way though not as elegant would be to call the system arp command from your C code and parse its output to get the MAC address. For example you can use
arp -n <destination_ip>

This will give you the MAC address of the destination but as you mentioned parsing the output isn’t ideal and can feel inefficient If you want a more native solution without using arp, you could dig into writing raw sockets for ARP but that would require crafting your own ARP requests and handling the responses If you’re okay with the arp command being a temporary solution while you explore more advanced options that’s probably the quickest way to move forward
Hope this helps and good luck with your networking project

You are not able to resolve destination MAC in some cases:
The destination of a TCP connection may not have ethernet MAC address at all.
For example when the destination is using other kind of network than ethernet.
When there are routers between local host and the destination, then the local host does not need to know MAC address of the destination of TCP connection. The local host uses MAC address of the local gateway as ethernet frame destination for transmitting TCP/IP packets towards the destination.
